# TypeError: oauth_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have abstract class SocialLogIn with method get_provider.

```
class SocialLogIn:
    def __init__(self, token, provider_name):
        self.id_token = token
        self.provider_name = provider_name

    def get_provider(self):
        module_name = 'oauth.{}'.format(self.provider_name)
        model = importlib.import_module(module_name)
        return inspect.getmembers(model, inspect.isclass)[0][1]
```

This method return class object class 'oauth.facebook.FacebookSignIn'. And this class object inherited from SocialLogIn :

```
class FacebookSignIn(SocialLogIn):

    def oauth_callback(self):
        return print('print')
```

But when i call method oauth_callback, I received TypeError.

```
provider = SocialLogIn(self.token, self.provider_name).get_provider()
response = provider.oauth_callback()
```

In provider i get facebook class object.

I try to make instance before calling oauth_callback and try super().**init**. But error still the same.

Comment: Your `get_provider` returns a class. That class must be instantiated before you can call its `oauth_callback` method…

Comment: As deceze is saying `response = provider().oauth_callback()`

Comment: I create provider().oauth_callback but it say that i need add token and provider to my constructor. But i added it in my parent class. and it's not work

Comment: `FacebookSignIn` inherits its `__init__` from `SocialLogIn`. You also need to pass a token and provider_name to it when you want to instantiate it.